# Adding javascript to webbrowser tool in windows phone 7

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, browser

I am developing a wp application in which there is a webbrowser which loads a web page. I want to add javascript file which fills a text box in loaded web page with some data and click on submit button. I want this javascript file to run automatically once webbrowser tool loads web page completely.

Answer (score 1):

When the web browser completely loads a page, the `Navigated` event will fire.
In the event handler, you can execute arbitrary JavaScript code by calling `theBrazza.InvokeScript( "eval", SomeJavaScriptSource );` where `SomeJavaScriptSource` is a variable or constant containing the JavaScript you’d like to run (just don't forget to specify `IsScriptEnabled="True"` in your web browser).

If your page already has any JavaScript code in it - you'll be fine, otherwise [this approach wont work](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/12505b6c-c3b7-4278-b4fd-0b3d136c3bb2/using-webbrowserinvokescripteval-fails-if-there-are-no-script-tags-on-the-page): that thread is old, however now in Windows Phone 8 the problem is still present :-(

Comment: can u share me example link for javascript

Comment: `const string SomeJavaScriptSource = @"document.getElementById('username').value=""moo""; document.forms[0].submit();"`

Comment: Am unable to do. Am getting error 80020101 ... Any solution?